# recordSetVar for Custom Object

Tags: list, list-view

On click of custom object tab  its showing recent view.I am trying to override recent view  with the list view tab of custom object.Here is my code

```
    <apex:page action="/{!$ObjectType.Application__c.keyPrefix}" standardController="Application__c" recordSetVar="applications">
</apex:page>
```

What should be the value of recordsetVar for custom object..Is it Object Api Name..because I see for Account object it is accounts and for Contact  it is contacts but not sure for custom object?

> The recordSetVar attribute not only indicates that the page uses a list controller, it can indicates the variable name of the record collection. This variable can be used to access data in the record collection.

Comment: The RecodSetVar is whatever you want it to be...

Comment: You're not using it so it doesn't really matter...it just creates a reference and enables you to add the page to list buttons.